# Nodejs Cassandra auto paging not working

Tags: node.js, solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-node-driver

I'm using Cassandra + Solr and the query is with "solr_query", always getting up to 10 results.
This is the amount from:

```
<requestHandler class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true" name="search">
<lst name="defaults">
<int name="rows">10</int>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I'm using eachRow to paginate the results and it's not working, it's get only the first 10 results and that's it.

```
var query = 'SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE solr_query = ?';
var solr_query = '{"q":"some_query"}';
this.client.eachRow(query, [solr_query], { prepare: true, autoPage : true, fetchSize: 100 }, function(index, result) {

}, callbackFunc);
```

In the fetchSize I've put 100 and still get only 10 results, if I'm adding LIMIT to the query it will work but still not paginate, it's stopped after the first page.

-- UPDTAE
Also I have try to use this function and the same result (10):

```
this.client.stream(query, [solr_query], { prepare: true }).on('readable', function () {
    var row;

    while (row = this.read()) {
        contacts.push(row);
    }
})
.on('end', function () {
    console.log(contacts.length); // 10
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When using Search component, these are 2 different settings - `LIMIT` controls how many entries Cassandra will return, and `fetchSize` specifies how big are pages that are returned by Cassandra. If you have many results, then you need to adjust `LIMIT` accordingly, although for big datasets it could be not very optimal.

Comment: What you mean by "fetchSize specifies how big are pages that are returned by Cassandra" http://datastax.github.io/nodejs-driver/features/paging/ here it say it's taking the rows the same setting as the limit.

Comment: This is true for Cassandra part because Cassandra returns all data matching condition, but when using with Search component this is slightly different - let me put this into answer...

Comment: What will be the solution to get all the rows?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that parameter `rows` which is set to 10 bounding the query? Here is the link for the docs [LINK](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/requesthandlers-and-searchcomponents-in-solrconfig.html#RequestHandlersandSearchComponentsinSolrConfig-SearchHandlers)

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I need it to work with the fetchSize.

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to query the Solr and not from Cassandra, I've used:
https://github.com/lbdremy/solr-node-client